# Npm unmet peer dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-native

I'm new to the Node and npm world.

I'm trying to setup a react native application and I encountered a scenario I'm not sure how to address.

Let's say I want to install two packages:

Package A which has a peer dependency of react ^0.14.0
Package B which has a peer dependency of react ^15.0.0

Obviously one of them would complain about unmet peer dependency.
How do you I resolve that ?

Comment: How did you solve this issue??

Answer (score 0):

add react ^15.0.0 to your package.json

Comment: But then the "^0.14.0" requirement (which means < 0.15.0) is unmet.